# Drupal Views Arguments

Tags: drupal-6, view, arguments

I know how to successfully use arguments in drupal's views module, but when it "filters" based on those arguments it uses "=" in the where clause of the SQL statement. However, I would like to use "like" instead of "=" in the where clause of the SQL statement so I can pass in, say the title of a node, as an argument and then show all nodes that CONTAIN the title passed in. I am not interested in grabbing only the nodes where the title is exactly the same as the title passed in. Does anyone know how I can do this? Is this possible?

Comment: Great question..facing same problem..if you got any solution..please dont forgot to post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possible solution would be to generate the view by code with your required query.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I might do this? If I do this can I then edit the view using the Views UI?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same solution. It looks like you can modify the query using the views_views_pre_execute hook. The link below has a pretty good explanation. Haven't tried it yet but giving it a shot now...

http://drupal.org/node/409808

Answer (score 0):

You could *export* the view, which outputs the views-generated query as code, then modify the query to suit your needs, and load it programatically (http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2010/01/15/how-to-programmatically-create-views-in-drupal-6)

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 7 you can use views query alter to generate your custom querys:

Take a look at this example: https://gist.github.com/4001074

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. See here (https://www.drupal.org/node/1578564):

> There are no options for selecting which operator should be used with contextual filters (save the exclude option). All default to is equal to.